# check username in table 1 and return data from table 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can i check a password matching a username and returning data from other table.

i have 2 tables. `Users and Lists`. In the `lists` table i have a column for email and some more in the users table i have a column for email and password. 
how can i check the username and password and match the corresponding values from the `lists` table?

What is tried were some joins but my problem is i am running it on a php file..
So it needs to be run from there as well.

this is my query to check in 1 database.

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM users 
        WHERE Email = '$email' 
            AND Password = '$password'"
```

i think is should be something like

```
$sql = "SELECT colomn1
              ,colomn2
              ,colomn3 
        FROM list 
        WHERE email = $email 
            and password = $password 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN lists.email 
            on users.email.
```

[tables http://www.project-hr.nl/tables.png](http://www.project-hr.nl/tables.png)

Comment: What is the username? Does every column a of `lists` have a valid username for given `email`?

Comment: your sql syntax is wrong. it goes `select ... from ... join ... where ...`

Comment: Are you after: `SELECT colomn1, colomn2, colomn3 
FROM list l 
LEFT INNER JOIN users u ON l.email = u.email
WHERE l.email = $email 
AND l.password = $password`

Comment: First thing, don't you know about foreign keys? second db error, you can't maintain that kind of database, what if the email is changed?should you change both tables? last thing, left join could do the job by selecting *, or specific field per tables using joins

Comment: LEFT INNER? That's a new one on me ;-)

Comment: The `$username` and `$passwhere` in that string scare me...

Comment: its hashed and salted don't worry ;)

Comment: @user3616687 Are your columns actually called `colomn1, colomn2, colomn3`? The proper spelling is `column`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

```
$sql= "SELECT 
           colomn1, colomn2, colomn3
       FROM
           list
               LEFT JOIN
           users USING (email)
       WHERE
           list.email = '$email'
               AND list.password = '$passwhere'"
```

Comment: re: @Fred -ii-'s edit, are they "typos" if I am copying the OP's wording? Maybe his columns are actually named "colomn1" and "colomn2". We do not know.

Comment: I doubt very much the OP is using `colomnX` see OP's table structure in images.

Comment: Am checking with OP now. If OP is using those actual names, I will edit accordingly, yet I doubt it but we'll see ;-) OP did accept your answer after I made the edit.

Comment: For argument's sake, I've edited back to the way it was. Will +1 for the trouble and the fact that this is a good answer. Cheers